# Insert last not null value in temp table by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE #ExchRates
(
  [TimeId] int,
  [CurrencyId] INT,
  [ExchRate] DECIMAL(30,6)
)    

INSERT INTO #ExchRates ([TimeId], [CurrencyId], [ExchRate])
  VALUES
    (
        2017030500,
        3,
        6.142911
    ),
    (
        2017030600,
        3,
        6.152911
    ),
    (
        2017030700,
        3,
        NULL
    ),
    (
        2017030800,
        3,
        5.5
    )
```

;

I want to insert values from this table in other table for one particular day(TimeId BETWEEN GETUTCDATE()-1 AND GETUTCDATE). Problem is when ExchRate is not set (NULL in table #ExchRate). In that case I want to use last known ExchRate for that currency. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: So you just need the most recent not-null exchange rate by each currency?

Comment: Add some more sample table data, with other CurrencyId's etc. And also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimeID DESC) RN 
    FROM #ExchRates
    WHERE ExchRate IS NOT NULL
) A WHERE RN = 1
```

If you have more than one currency in the table, you can do this following -

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CurrencyId ORDER BY TimeID DESC) RN 
    FROM #ExchRates
    WHERE ExchRate IS NOT NULL
) A WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Yes i have 10 or more currencies and each day exchange rate is changing for all currencies. Also question is how to get from #ExchRates filter by time (getdate-2 and getdate-1). What does WHERE RN=1 does?

Comment: By WHERE RN = 1, The query will keep only 1 row per CurrencyId which is the row with Max Date Time for that CurrencyId. Finally this will keep on row per CurrencyId.

Comment: @user2171512 can you please explain a bit more about your filter by time getdate-2 and getdate-1

Comment: Ok but i calculate exchange rates for some @StartDate - 1 day, not for my last known Exchange rate day

Comment: Can you make things more clear please? Just post your expected output from your inserted data.

Answer (score 2):

for the case of null you can use row_number() for getting the last value

```
  select * from (select *,row_number() over(partition by CurrencyId order by TimeId desc) rn
    from #ExchRates
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your query.

```
insert into Table2 ([TimeId], [CurrencyId], [ExchRate])
select  ([TimeId], [CurrencyId], [ExchRate]), 
    isnull([ExchRate], (select top 1 [ExchRate] from #ExchRates order by [TimeId] desc)) from #ExchRates
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the last record you want :

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CurrencyId ORDER BY TimeId DESC) rn
    FROM #ExchRates )

SELECT
    *
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: is there any difference between yours & Zaynul Abadin Tuhin's one?